# Верстка сайта, кнопки-меню по периметру области

Tags: html, css, jquery, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Появилась проблема с версткой меню сайта. Серверная технология используемая asp.net mvc.
По периметру области страницы должны быть расположены кнопки-меню, постарался в Paint нарисовать.В верхней и нижней части страницы панель с информацией.
При клике на меню-кнопки расположенные слева, должна выехать меню слева страницы на какой-то процент. При клике на меню верхней части, должна выехать панель на все страницу. Аналогично справа и внизу.
Каким образом, инструментом такое можно сделать?
Сами меню (в виде трапеций) как нарисовать и расположить указанным способом?
Я думал взять нарисовать саму кнопку, взять ее картинку и для кнопки указать эту картинку..+ вопрос панелек.
Может кто нечто похожее делал и может подсказать
[image: схематичный вид]

Comment: Уменьшите картинку, это что за ужас такой?

Comment: Не заметил сразу, убрал пустое место,уменьшил картинку